# Estimation of Nonzero Coefficients of Binary Cylotomic Polynomials

Tags: analytic-number-theory, estimation-theory

I am reading Fouvry's paper https://msp.org/ant/2013/7-5/ant-v7-n5-p07-p.pdf . I am still confused on section 4.2 why $P\leq x^{\frac{20}{9}\gamma -\frac{2}{3}}\mathcal{L}^{-16}$ leads to estimate in proposition 1 for $O(Q\mathcal{L}^{-4})$. I got the implication $P\geq x^{1-2\gamma}\mathcal{L}^{14}$ to error term $O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\gamma}\mathcal{L}^{-6})$ but not the other one. On section 4.3 I tried calculations but did not get the estimates for both lower and upper bounds.

Comment: which error do find too big? the first or second in the error term, or the one coming from the error term in the main term?

Comment: @tomos for me it's the second error term, I could not manage to get $O(Q\mathcal{L}^{-4})$ from given information

Comment: no no i mean of (36).  which of those error terms is too big for you?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by too big

Comment: there are 3 error terms in (36).  which can you not show to be smaller than the errors in prop 1

Comment: Ah, the third one, with $P^{5/4}Q^{4/5}$ term

Comment: ignoring $\log $'s and using crudely $Q^{4/5}\leq Q$, the third error is $\ll P^{5/4}Q\leq x^{25\gamma /9-5/6}Q=x^{1/2+\gamma }Qx^{16\gamma /9-4/3}$.  so if $\gamma \approx 1/2$ (which i assume is how we're supposed to think of it, but not 100% sure) then the third error is $\ll x^{1/2+\gamma }Qx^{-4/9}$ and (21) says the $Q$ factor should be small.  making this explicit you'd need to write $\gamma =1/2+\text { small} $

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand it better

Comment: I think I got the idea. We can write $P^{5/4}Q^{4/5}$ as $(PQ)^{4/5}P^{9/20}\ll x^{4/5}P^{9/20}$ and then we can use the bound for $P$.

Comment: ah ye, that seems smarter than what i did